# create-react-app - Fetch Local JSON (via AJAX)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to do something rather simple with `create-react-app`, dynamically request a JSON file from somewhere else on the front-end. When I request the URL, Webpack just returns the `index` page of the app (with an HTTP 200).

I've tried placing the JSON files in both the `src` and `public` dirs, but it didn't make a difference (e.g., `/src/data/stuff.json`, `/public/data/stuff.json`).

I'm guessing webpack / something is preventing the request from going through.

Something like `fetch('http://localhost:3000/public/data/stuff.json')` just doesn't work. I see the request, but the response is just the default HTML.

Neither, of course, do `http://localhost:3000/src/data/stuff.json` or `http://localhost:3000/data/stuff.json`.

I'm fetching this dynamically rather than importing since I just want this one JSON file (I believe webpack would bundle all of them in the app; not to mention IRL the filename is dynamic, something closer to `file-{date}.json` with a large archive).

Would definitely love any and all help and bits of advice. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

`create-react-app` uses `webpack-dev-server` as a, uh, dev server. `webpack-dev-server` uses [`connect-history-api-fallback`](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) to serve the `index.html` file for every request (to allow for client-side routing). By default, the `connect-history-api-fallback` will NOT override paths with a dot (like `/data/stuff.json`). However, `create-react-app` [*disables* this setting](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L85).

So you'll need to set `disableDotRule` to `false` [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L85). You may need to `eject` in order to modify this config.

This setting depends on the server you're using though, so you may get different behavior when you aren't using `webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: By the way, I think the `create-react-app` team would recommend that you import the JSON file in your application, or use a separate database of some sort if the data changes often.

Comment: Good to know - `eject`ing + disabling that setting + restarting webpack now shows a 404, though the path exists.

```http://localhost:3000/public/stuff/data-2017-09-24.json -> 
Cannot GET /public/stuff/data-2017-09-24.json```

But `ls`-ing in the root directory for the app does show the file (`./public/stuff/data-2017-09-24.json`)

Comment: If the file is `/public/data/stuff.json` I believe you'll access it with `/data/stuff.json`

Comment: Duh - that worked!

It stinks that I have to `eject` just to flip a bit in the config, but I appreciate the help :)

Comment: The reason why I'm fetching rather than importing is because these json files contain index data for a large media file (like an mp3).

It would be quite ridiculous to load all the indices for all the media files into the system at runtime, plus we can't `require` dynamic paths (right?).

Comment: `require` calls are handled like `import` by webpack; the code is inlined into a single file. They discourage [use of the public folder](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-the-public-folder) for a few reasons (listed on that linked page). But if you have, for example, thousands of dynamically loaded images, you'd wouldn't want them inlined. On the other hand, if this JSON file is ALWAYS used, it's fine to `import` it into your source code.

Comment: Right, but I'm saying that the paths are dynamic, the file names are determined at *run-time* and not *build-time*, which has historically caused an issue with webpack.

Not to mention you can't exactly `import` in the middle of a function.

BY THE WAY - after I got this to work, I reverted to another branch that hadn't done `eject`ed, restarted webpack, and it still worked, though it hadn't before. Who knows.